# How to render text into HTML in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable in a scope with some HTML content. I want to render it as HTML on the webpage, but in my case it displays as full text. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:-

**//contoller.js**

```
$scope.message = '<b><i>result has been saved successfully.</i></b>';
```

**//demo.html**

```
<p ng-bind="message"></p>
```

Comment: Why do you need html string in controller and not template this?

Comment: because i wanted to display a successfull message while user click on Save Button and i want that message look good.

Comment: So make it look good in the template and pass in text...that is the normal approach.

Comment: don't i use in controller. If i want?

Comment: Makes no sense doing it in controller. no separation of concerns and requires more complicated process to inject it. That's what templates are for

Comment: yes bro, you are ri8. actually i am making a project and i am in a learning phase now. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to inject [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service into your `controller` or `Directive` etc. and use `$sce service` like this:-

```
$scope.Message = $sce.trustAsHtml("<b><i>result has been saved successfully.</i></b>");
```

And bind this in your HTML page  e.g;

```
<p ng-bind-html = "Message"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to secure your content with the $sce service and then use the

`ng-bind-html` directive

[docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

---

**EDIT**

you can find the usage of `sce.trustAsHtml` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml).

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you'll enjoy your angular experience!

Answer (score 1):

```
<p ng-bind-html="message"></p>
```

Comment: ng-bind-html what more explanation is needed? this should solve the problem